# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined using promises

Tags: javascript, express, promise, routes

I am making this website as a project which is a "Walmart" version of AirBnB.

Here's what the button is supposed to do for context:

A user will click on a "Make Reservation" button on a listing.
They will select a start and end date then submit. This will send an HTTP request to the server.

However, I am running into an error where it returns :

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at /vagrant/LightBnB/LightBnB_WEB_APP/server/apiRoutes.js:44:7 <--

The line 44:7 is the API route below:

This is causing the error:

```
.then((reservation) => {
            res.send(reservation);
```

This is the API ROUTE Logic which is causing an issue:

```
  router.post('/reservations', (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.session.userId;
    database
      .addReservation({ ...req.body, guest_id: userId })
      .then((reservation) => {
        res.send(reservation);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
        res.send(e);
      });
  });
```

That route is calling the function addReservation() which is the following:

```
    /**
 * Add a reservation to the database
 * @param {{}} reservation An object containing all of the reservation details.
 * @return {Promise<{}>} A promise to the reservation.
 */
const addReservation = function (reservation) {
  const queryString = `
  INSERT INTO reservations(
    start_date,
    end_date,
    property_id,
    guest_id 
  ) 
  VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
  RETURNING *
  `;
  const values = [
    reservation.start_date,
    reservation.end_date,
    reservation.property_id,
    reservation.guest_id,
  ];
  pool
    .query(queryString, values)
    .then((res) => {
      res.rows;
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
};
exports.addReservation = addReservation;
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

`addReservation()` has no return value, thus it returns `undefined`.  So, when you try to do `addReservation(...).then(...)`, you end up trying to access `.then()` on `undefined` which results in the error you get.

Inside of `addReservation()`, you need to change:

```
pool.query(...).then(...).catch(...)
```

to

```
return pool.query(...).then(...).catch(...)
```

That returns your promise so then the caller can use `.then()` on the returned promise.

---

Note, your `.catch()` handler in `addReservation()` is logging and then "eating" the error.  You should probably rethrow the error so that the caller can see the error:

Change this:

```
.catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
```

to this:

```
.catch((e) => {
     console.log(e.message)
     // re-throw the error so it propagates to the caller
     throw e;
});
```

---

Also, note that `res.send(e)` probably won't provide much useful info because most properties of the Error object are not enumerable and thus won't show up when `res.send()` turns the Error object into JSON.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe this is what was missing the whole time. My other functions were returning the pool but this one wasn't..